# Laravel Eloquent query with relationship table with where and wherehas

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

Following query is ignoring the `where('contact_id',$id)` causing to return results that does not belong to this contact. Why?

```
Transaction::where('contact_id',$id)
            ->with('allocations')
            ->whereHas("allocations",function ($query){
            $query->select('transaction_id')
                ->havingRaw('transactions.amount > sum(amount)')
                ->groupBy('transaction_id');
            })
            ->orDoesntHave("allocations")
            ->get();
```

if I remove the whereHas part, it is bringing back the correct result. But I need the whereHas part.

```
            ->whereHas("allocations",function ($query){
            $query->select('transaction_id')
                ->havingRaw('transactions.amount > sum(amount)')
                ->groupBy('transaction_id');
            })
            ->orDoesntHave("allocations")
```

Basically, I am trying to query for transactions where the transaction amount is greater than the sum of allocations (transaction hasMany allocations) for that transaction.

Comment: you mean to say where('contact_id',$id) fails ?

Comment: yes, where('contact_id',$id) fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the problem is this line

```
->orDoesntHave("allocations")
```

because the logic of your condition looks like this (in SQL)

```
WHERE contact_id = ... AND count_subquery_allocations > 0 OR count_have_no_allocations = 0
```

as you can see that `OR` "makes the condition true" even if `contact_id = ...` is false... you probably want this:

```
Transaction::where('contact_id',$id)
    ->where(function($query){
        return $query->whereHas("allocations",function ($query){
                return $query->select('transaction_id')
                    ->havingRaw('transactions.amount > sum(amount)')
                    ->groupBy('transaction_id');
            })
            ->orDoesntHave("allocations");
    })
    ->with('allocations')
    ->get();
```

Comment: exactly what i was thinking for .Good one :)

Comment: @JohnLobo I've encounter this problem so many times ahah

Comment: this worked. Thank you.  Quick clarification, does it require to have '->with('allocations')' in the second last line. I removed it and it still works. I was checking laravel documentation and they don't seem to be using 'with' along with 'whereHas'.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: @Thaha `with` is used to "eager load" some relations, to avoid the N+1 problem (search on google and you will find tons of blog talking about it)... so obviously, the only difference in using it/not using it, is in performance (if you will actually use that relation)... and no, the `with` inside the function where there is the `whereHas` makes no sense